# SharpDX Not Implemented Exception

Tags: c#, .net, directx, sharpdx

What could be the reason I am getting a SharpDX NotImplemented Exception?

```
SharpDX.SharpDXException: HRESULT: [0x80004001], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_NOTIMPL/Not implemented], Message: Not implemented
at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()
at SharpDX.MediaFoundation.MediaFactory.Startup(Int32 version, Int32 dwFlags)
at SharpDX.MediaFoundation.MediaManager.Startup(Boolean useLightVersion)
```

this is on windows 8 desktop. the same code runs fine on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at native call for [MFStartup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Seems it can happen when media components are not installed.

Here is a [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2703761) with media feature pack download, hopefully should sort your problem (no idea why this is not here by default).

Comment: good point! it is indeed a windows 8 N edition. ill give that a try!